# How is .NET breaking in this catch block after an await using?

Tags: c#, async-await, dispose, .net-7.0

We are using a .NET 7 generated service (from a WSDL) that inherits `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase` which implements `IAsyncDisposable`. The `ClientBase` client is generated by VS2022.

This service *should* work with `await using`:

```cs
await using var client = new GeneratedClient(...);

try
{
    var response = await client.generatedRpc(...);
    ... do stuff
    return GetResult(response.someProperty);
}
catch (Exception ex)
    when (... some check of the message )
{
    throw new SpecificException(ex.Message, ex); // breaks here when await using
}
```

This crashes, but on debug `await client.generatedRpc(...` works fine, `response.someProperty` is populated as expected, but it jumps to the `catch` on the `throw new` line.

How has this broken into the `catch`? The `ex` variable is out of scope, so we thought this was IL/.cs files getting out of sync, but clean builds break at the same point.

If we change this from `await using` to just `using` the crash doesn't happen!

I think the `await using` syntax sugar should compile to something like:

```cs
var client = new GeneratedClient(...);
try
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GeneratedRpc(...);
        ... do stuff
        return GetResult(response.someProperty);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        when (... some check of the message )
    {
        throw new SpecificException(ex.Message, ex); // breaks here
    }
}
finally {
    await client.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Then, in that `finally`:

- `await using` does `await client.DisposeAsync();`
- `using` does `client.Dispose();` instead

As `using` works that suggests the blocking synchronous `Dispose` method doesn't throw an exception while the non-blocking asynchronous `DisposeAsync` does.

I don't know where to start trying to fix this:

- Why does `await using` crash when `using` doesn't?
- How does a exception in `DisposeAsync` in the outer `try-finally` break in the inner `try-catch`?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this *without* WSDL involved? If you could create a [mcve] that would make it much easier to help.

Comment: "The ex variable is out of scope" - that's definitely weird. But it would be good if you could show the full stack trace, including the inner exception. Run it without the debugger attached, to take that out of the picture.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash" though? What exactly happens? We really need a [mre]

Comment: Are you debugging a Release build? Due to optimizations, the debugger might display a wrong current line. Is `SpecificException` thrown?

Comment: @JonSkeet we've got `await using` all over the code, but this is the only `ClientBase` generated with a WSDL we have and it's the only place we've see the exception. I'll reproduce and get the full stack.

Comment: @DavidG I realise, but this is in a closed source app calling generated code from a paid service WSDL that is about 8k - I've no idea even where to _start_ with a minimal reproduction when this doesn't happen anywhere else. That's what I'm asking really: how would you even make this happen if you wanted to crash like this?

Comment: @JonSkeet disconnecting the debugger appeared to fix the issue, but then the logs showed errors with reset stacks (like a `throw new ...`). I think that's because this is a web API and the exception occurs after the response stream has been built, but I'll have to do some work to test that.

Answer (score 0):

When .NET7 auto generates a `ClientBase` implementation it doesn't correctly implement `IAsyncDisposable`, it simply aliases `ClientBase.CloseAsync()`.

However, `CloseAsync` throws exceptions if for any reason the underling connection is not open, if it's closed (or errored) `Abort` needs to be called instead.

The fix appears to be to call this directly instead of relying on `using` or `await using`:

```cs
var client = new GeneratedClient(...);

try
{
    var response = await client.generatedRpc(...);
    ... do stuff
    return GetResult(response.someProperty);
}
finally {
    try
    {
        // Only want to call Close if it is in the Opened state
        if (client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            await client.CloseAsync();

        // Anything not closed by this point should be aborted
        if (client.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            client.Abort();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException) { client.Abort(); }
    catch (CommunicationException) { client.Abort(); }
}
```